# What is the intended goal of Level 5-3, in the Kremlin?

Tags: soviet-kitchen-unleashed

When playing Level 5-3 (Kremlin) we have to uncover enemy spies. We guess it has something to do with the US flag on top of the Hamburger, but we do not understand what to do.

We tried to poison them, no effect, we took a photo when the burger was there, also no result. We understand this is some kind of a puzzle, but we do not get it.

What exactly are we meant to do in this mission?

Comment: I'm voting to close because it's not clear what game this question is about, and I strongly suspect it's actually a video game from the nature of the problem being described.

Comment: @doppelgreener It sounds like this is a hybrid table-top and mobile game that involves scanning cards into an app with your phone's camera.

Comment: @nick012000 it is a coop card game, but comes with a companion app which handles the point counting and tells about the slightly changing rules from round to round. also it contains kind of an interactive color-wheel. It is definitively not a video game, have a look https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/260407/soviet-kitchen-unleashed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We were blocked too but we found the answer thanks to your remark. You have to poison only your ennemies with the two American burgers, not the other meals.

Have a good game